# Java & SQL: Querying A Database To Output Records With Only Future/Past Dates

Tags: java, sql, database, netbeans, derby

I have a form with a JTable where business appointments and events (stored in a Derby database) are displayed - a problem I am having is implementing a feature that will display only 'Past/Upcoming Events' by using the event dates from the database.

I have a JComboBox on the form which lists 'All', 'Upcoming', and 'Past Events' accompanied by a JButton. Once pressed a series of IF statements determine which SQL query should be used to populate the JTable, by calling a PopulateTable method which uses a JTable and SQL Query as parameters, as shown below:

```
    private void updateSelectionBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {               

        if(updateBox.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("All Events")){
            PopulateTable(eventsTable, "SELECT * FROM EVENTS");
        }
```

If 'All Events' is selected, the table will be populated with all records. The above code works fine, however, I can't seem to find a solution which would allow events to be selected by dates. In an SQL query such as:

```
SELECT * FROM EVENT WHERE EVENT_DATE >= "TODAY'S_DATE?"
```

The 'Event_Dates' are stored in the database as Strings, originally saved from a JDatePicker.

Any help or advice is appreciated,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you please post sample of String in databse

Comment: If you're using a string datatype for your date columns, such as `CHAR` or `VARCHAR`, then the `>=` or `<=` are interpreted using string comparison. If you're using a `DATE` datatype for your date columns, then the `>=` is interpreted using date semantics. Is that your question?

Comment: Dates are stored in the database as `VARCHAR`. Eg. 06/01/2017. I'm trying to find a way of outputting all records with a date 'more' or 'less' than today, i.e Records with dates only in the future or past